# Why do I get "Error: JWT_KEY must be defined"?

Tags: jwt, windows-10, kubectl, docker-desktop, secret-key

I am trying to run a project that uses `docker` and `kubernetes`.  When I try to run the application it gives me the following error:

```
> auth@1.0.0 start        
> ts-node-dev src/index.ts

[INFO] 11:03:41 ts-node-dev ver. 2.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 10.8.2, typescript ver. 4.7.4)
Error: JWT_KEY must be defined
    at E:\adv\shop_back\auth\src\index.ts:7:11
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at E:\adv\shop_back\auth\src\index.ts:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (E:\adv\shop_back\auth\src\index.ts:4:12)
    at start (E:\adv\shop_back\auth\src\index.ts:5:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\adv\shop_back\auth\src\index.ts:25:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)      
    at Module._compile (E:\adv\shop_back\auth\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:521:25)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-2465378030590002.js:69:33)
[ERROR] 11:03:48 Error: JWT_KEY must be defined
```

I tried to create a `JWT_KEY` using the following command:

```
kubectl create secret generic jwt-secret --from-literal JWT_KEY=this_is_the_jwt_key
```

But it responses with a new error:

```
error: failed to create secret secrets "jwt-secret" already exists
```

I remember I have used the `kubectl create secret ...` command previously for testing another project( although with a different expression after `=`, like `JWT_KEY=asdf`).

I don't know where these keys get stored? Why the new program doesn't work if there is a `JWT_KEY` already stored?

PS: I use Windows 10 machine and Docker-Desktop app.

This is my `index.js` file:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

import { app } from "./app";

const start = async () => {
  if (!process.env.JWT_KEY) {
    throw new Error("JWT_KEY must be defined");
  }
  if (!process.env.MONGO_URI) {
    throw new Error("MONGO_URI must be defined");
  }

  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {});
    console.log("Connected to MongoDb");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000!!!!!!!!");
  });
};

start();
```

When I run `kubectl get secrets` I get:

```
kubectl get secrets
NAME            TYPE     DATA   AGE
jwt-secret      Opaque   1      38d
```

This is the `deployment.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: tester/auth
          env:
            - name: MONGO_URI
              value: 'mongodb://auth-mongo-srv:27017/auth'
            - name: JWT_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jwt-secret
                  key: JWT_KEY
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete your key by using:
kubectl delete secret jwt-secret

Then you may create again
kubectl create secret generic jwt-secret --from-literal JWT_KEY=asdf